# Syntax for sheet.getrange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a new convert to Google from Microsoft and the comfort of VBA!

In a Spreadsheet I use

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getMaxRows()-1,sheet.getMaxColumns());
```

to work on all the columns and sort on multiple columns.

What I need to do is ignore the data in the first column and sort the rest.

An explained solution would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `range.getValues()` you will get a 2 dimension javascript array, you can sort it the way you want and then you can rewrite its value to the sheet using

`sheet.getRange(2,1, array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);`